# Play Spotify Preview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, spotify

I wanna play spotify track's preview in my app(Like instagram story music section). Its simple Spotify preview [example url](https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/1018d9eec93e59419426f0fb2b1da409b043661a?cid=ed39ab3239754f0ca3cda04314c50dbc)
But when I try just_audio or audioassets plugin
I get error like this.

> codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)

How can I play spotify preview mp3 in my app?

Answer (score 1):

Do it Hope this will help you ,

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }
```